# Do all android devices above a certain api support mtp?

Tags: android, usb, mtp

I need to develop an app for windows for data transfers to android devices via mtp. That is when android is connected to windows via USB cable and android offers mtp menu as protocol for USB.

Can someone tell from which android version onwards can I assume that the device definitely has mtp support. Can this assumption be even made ?

Secondly is it android feature or does the mtp support depends on manufacturer regardless of android version ?

Comment: Are you using any libraries?I am also developing an simillar application and I would like to know

Comment: @cssGEEK I have given up on it for now as there is not enough documentation available on mtp unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) for Lollipop/Android 5.0 section 7.6.2 states that:

```
Device implementations MAY use USB mass storage, but SHOULD use Media Transfer Protocol
```

As it doesn't read 'MUST', I'm afraid there are no guarantees that devices which would have Google Play would have MTP, but I would be surprised if the major manufacturers didn't follow it and have an MTP implementation.

You can check the documents for older version of Android here:

http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html

Answer (score -1):

The [MTP] was added since Android API 12,
which Platform Version is [Android 3.1.x].

so, the [above a certain api] may be android 3.1

and ,this is the android feature,and I think the manufactur has no reason to unenable it.

[Android API : developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/package-summary.html)

Comment: Please be more specific, and while posting an answer please make sure your answer is what the OP asking for.